# isBizday not working and returning an that is not an S4 object error

Tags: r

I'm not sure why my function isBizday is not working. The error I'm getting is:

> Error in isBizday(Dates, holidayTSX()) : 
>     trying to get slot "Data" from an object (class "Date") that is not an S4 object

My code:

```
Dates[isBizday(Dates, holidayTSX())]
```

How should I go about correcting this error?

An example of my data:

```
Dates<-structure(c(15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 
15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 
15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 
15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 
15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 
15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 
15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 
15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 
15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 
15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 
15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15340, 15341, 
15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 
15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 
15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 
15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 
15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 
15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 
15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 
15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 
15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 
15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 
15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 15341, 15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 
15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 
15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 
15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 
15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 
15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 
15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 
15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 
15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 
15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 
15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 15342, 
15342, 15342), class = "Date")
```

Comment: I would suggest, that you review my answer, and accept it or give any other feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You probably are talking about function `isBizday` from `timeDate` package. So firstly you should read documentation of this function [[here]](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/timeDate/versions/2100.86/topics/isBizday).
There is written that:

x is an object of class timeDate.

So you need to convert your dates:

```
d <- as.timeDate(Dates)
isBizday(d)
```